# Send commands to a Process ID (PID)

Tags: windows, perl

I have command prompt open and found its pid to be 4422.

Knowing the pid, is it possible to send and a command to this cmd window. How would you make the following appear on the cmd prompt from a Perl script:

```
echo "hello world"
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Maybe you want to open a subshell instead and feed commands to that?

Comment: If you just want text to appear in a particular terminal window, you can open its tty and send characters to it.

Comment: I need to be able to run a command on a Putty window which another script launched. I can find the pid of the Putty window but don't know how to pass in something to it

Comment: So I figured if I could be able to run a command on process given a pid, I might get it to work

Comment: You can use AutoHotKey in Windows to send arbitrary text to any window.

Comment: I need a universal method. I need to check if it's already installed on the PCs

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is no - processes are complex things, and so injecting arbitrary stuff into them is both difficult and fundamentally at odds with decent system design.

In some specific cases it can be done, but it's not a good idea because you simply don't know the state of the process you're interacting with.

This is why processes have inter-process communication mechanisms - so you can do this safely and rationally. If you don't have an IPC, then you're better off assuming that it simply cannot be done, and look for a less hacky solution to your problem.

Such as - on Unix - you can use `write` or similar.

Comment: Thanks. That's a better response. I wonder if there are any IPC modules available for injecting commands to other programs.

Comment: That's not the way it works. IPC is a consensual process.